# Issue in regular expressions

Tags: r

```
e
Material     newvar1 
5000    4.28 > 5 > 5
5001    3 > 2 > 3 > 3
```

When I apply the below code

```
e$newvar2=sapply(str_extract_all(gsub("\\b(\\c+\\.\\c+)(?:\\s+>\\s+\\1\\b)+", "\\1", e$newvar1), "\\d+\\.\\d+"), paste, collapse=" > ")
```

I get a wrong output like below

```
e
Material     newvar1         newvar2
5000        4.28 > 5         4.28
5001        3 > 2 > 3 > 3    3 > 2 > 3
```

Instead I need like below

```
e
Material     newvar1         newvar2
5000        4.28 > 5        4.28 > 5
5001        3 > 2 > 3 > 3    3 > 2 > 3
```

Comment: `newvar2` appears to be identical to `newvar1`.  What is the logic behind the transformation you want to do here?

Comment: Edited. Actually newvar1 has duplicate consecutive values and I need distinct values. Hope you got my point. Why am i getting only 4.28 instead of 4.28 > 5

Answer (score 1):

We can try using `str_replace_all` from the `stringr` library.  Find on the following pattern, and then remove it by replacing with empty string:

```
(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?) > (?=\\1)
```

This matches and captures a number, also matching the proceeding `>` symbol.  If looking ahead, we see the same number, then we remove the entire preceding number and `>` separator.

That is, `3 > 3` just becomes `3`.

```
x <- "3 > 2 > 3.28 > 3.28 > 1.5 > 1.5"
str_replace_all(x, "(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?) > (?=\\1)", "")

[1] "3 > 2 > 3.28 > 1.5"
```

Comment: Thanks. But again when I cross Check. I see for some lines. Repetitive numbers are not removed. For example  2 > 2 > 2is showing as 2 > 2 > 2 instead of 2. Why. Sorry i not able to post the data set here. It's confidential

Comment: @Rroaring `2 > 2 > 2` should become just `2` AFAIK.  Maybe your data has some problem.  Anyway, I cannot test right now.

Comment: Yes. That's my concern. Problem in the data means?? Because it is happening for many lines. Is it the above code does not work for large data sets? Or is there any problem??

Comment: You need to debug and get to the bottom of this.  It's OK to question my answer, but you should find it strange perhaps that it works most of the time, but not always.

Comment: I guessed it Tim, May be if the number is whole number like (2,3,5,7) the code is not executing. If the number is decimal like 2.3,3.4 etc, the code gets executed. Hope you got my point

Comment: @Rroaring You're right, and I've fixed my answer.  I made the decimal component optional.  I originally just wrote a pattern to cover whole numbers, then modified it to include decimals, not realizing that it no longer worked for whole numbers.